# How to disable certain org-mode blocks from accidental execution

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have some shell code that can be dangerous to run on local machine in a org-mode source code block. Globally, I have configured org-mode to prompt for execution, but I would still like to make sure that these blocks will NEVER be executed with per-block configuration.

Answer (score 3):

To explicitly disable certain org-mode code blocks from execution, add `:eval no` or `:noeval` in the code block header line. See the example below:

```
#+begin_src bash :noeval
sudo rm -rf /
#+end_src
```

When doing `C-c C-c` to attempt to run the code, the following message is produced:

```
Evaluation of this bash code block is disabled.
```

Comment: *FWIW* I experienced an issue where ```:noeval``` was not preventing the code block from executing for some odd reason. Switched to ```:eval no``` and it worked.